# A.S or R.A? Which one is right?

Tags: sharia, shiism, shia-sunni, honorifics

In Shia view, people use (Alayh Al Salam = A.S.) after the name of Imams, but in Sunni view, (Rathi Allahu Anh = R.A.) is used.

What is the reason behind or how do we know which one to use in this website?

Answer (score 2):

Both Sunni and Shia brothers respect a lot to Prophet Muhammad(PBUH), his family and Imams.

> قُل لَّا أَسْأَلُكُمْ عَلَيْهِ أَجْرًا إِلَّا الْمَوَدَّةَ فِي الْقُرْبَى - الشوري 23

Both Rathi-Allahu-Anh and Alayh-al-Salam are the signs of being respectful, but even not limited to these.

I believe no matters HOW to be respectful, every sign of being respectful is praised by Allah.